# removing "na" from a column and collapsing the row

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I would like to remove rows that have an "na"

file

```
0.000
0.000
0.055
0.036
0.003
0.002
0.000
0.002
0.002
0.002
0.000
na
na
0.000
0.000
na
0.002
0.002
0.003
```

output

```
0.000
0.000
0.055
0.036
0.003
0.002
0.000
0.002
0.002
0.002
0.000
0.000
0.000
0.002
0.002
0.003
```

I was trying to do this in R but i couldn't collapse the rows, just remove the na

Comment: With `grep -v na`. Removes all lines containing the string `na`.The `-v` is the short form for `--invert-match`.

Comment: If you decide you *do* want to do it in R, it would be something like `data = read.table("data.txt", na.strings = "na")` then `data = na.omit(data)` I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**With awk:**

```
awk '!/na/' file > new_file
```

The "!" means do not match.  The "/na/" specifies the pattern "na".  Together they mean do not match lines containing the pattern na.  The default behavior of awk is to print, but you can also specifically tell it to print (call the print function) like this:

```
awk '!/na/ {print}' file > new_file
```

To not print the empty lines in the file, use this regular expression.  !/^$/  This tells awk not to match on an empty line.  It will match by starting from the beginning of the line designated by a "^" to the end of the line designated with a "$" with no content in between.  The "&&" tells it to use both expressions when evaluating each line.

```
awk '!/na/ && !/^$/ {print}' file > new_file
```

**With sed:**

```
sed '/na/d' file > new_file
```

The "/d tells sed to delete the line containing the matched pattern "/na/"

To directly modify the source file, without needing to write to a new file, use the -i (in place) option with sed

```
sed -i '/na/d' file
```

**Using nothing but the bash shell with bash builtin:**

```
while read -r line; do [[ ! $line =~ na ]] && echo "$line"; done < file > o; mv o file
```

**With Python:**

```
with open('file', 'r') as rf:
  with open('out', 'w') as of:
    for line in rf:
      if not "na" in line:
        of.write(line)
```

As with all of the other examples, this will not leave a blank line, given the sample input provided in the original question.

```
$ cat file
0.000
0.000
0.055
0.036
0.003
0.002
0.000
0.002
0.002
0.002
0.000
0.000
0.000
0.002
0.002
0.003
```

Answer (score 1):

As simple as:

```
grep -v na file > new_file
```

Comment: You'd better use `-x` with `grep` here to only match across complete lines. I would probably use `grep -x -F -v na` to be absolutely correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
I tried with below 3 methods

1.using awk

command:awk '$0 !~/na/{print $0}' filename

2. using sed

sed -n '/na/!p' filename

3. using python

    #!/usr/bin/python
    import re
    k=open('filename','r')
    a=re.compile(r'[0-9]')
    for i in k:
            if re.search(a,i):
                    print i,
```

output

```
0.000
0.000
0.055
0.036
0.003
0.002
0.000
0.002
0.002
0.002
0.000
0.000
0.000
0.002
0.002
0.003
```